# Dynamically change video crop width, height, x and y using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am doing object detection on a video and so far I've gotten the coordinates of the objects in the video.

now I want to crop the video frame by frame given the location/coordinates of the object

My code so far:

```
def crop_video(input_video_path, output_video_path, coordinate_list):
    
    crop_ratio = 'crop=%s:%s:%s:%s' % (coordinate_list[0][0], coordinate_list[0][1], coordinate_list[0][2],coordinate_list[0][3])
    subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_video_path, '-filter:v', crop_ratio, output_video_path])
```

the `crop_video` function crops the entire video using only the first index in the coordinate_list list. How can I improve the code to change dynamically.
coordinate list looks similar to this:

```
 coordinate_list = [[147.5, 253.5, 927, 107],
     [147.5, 253.5, 927, 107],
     [147.0, 257.5, 928, 102],
     [148.5, 258.5, 925, 104],
     [148.5, 258.5, 925, 104],
     [155.0, 258.5, 918, 103],
     [155.0, 258.5, 918, 103],]
```

How can I dynamically change the crop width, height, x and y using the coordinate_list. I am new to using ffmpeg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [sendcmd](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) filter.

1. Make `commands.txt`:

   ```
   0    crop w 148,
        crop h 254,
        crop x 925,
        crop y 108;

   0.04 crop w 142,
        crop h 252,
        crop x 927,
        crop y 107;

   0.08 crop w 147,
        crop h 258,
        crop x 928,
        crop y 102;
   ```

   - The text does not have to be formatted exactly as above. I added line breaks for readability. You can place each timestamp on its own line if you prefer.
   - sendcmd works with timestamps, not frame numbers. This example shows frames 1-3 and assumes a frame rate of 25 (1/25 = 0.04).
   - Not all filters can use sendcmd (or the audio version asendcmd). See output of `ffmpeg -filters`. If the filter supports (a)sendcmd it will have a `T` preceding the filter name in the list.
   - Not all filter options can be used with sendcmd. See [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) and look for "Commands".
2. Run `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=commands.txt,crop" output_%03d.png
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want the output to be an mp4 file

Comment: @Mario Change `output_%03d.png` to `output.mp4`. Your question did not mention what output you wanted. Because the width and height change I assumed you wanted images. MP4 has some limitations to be aware of: 1) width and height must be divisible by 2 for compatible output. 2) Each frame must have the same width and height.