Fastest way to extract moving dynamic crop from video using ffmpeg
I'm working on an AI project that involves object detection and action recognition on roughly 30 minute videos.
My pipeline is the following:

determine crops using object detection model
extract crops using Python and write them to disk as individual images for each frame.
use action recognition model by inputting a series of the crops.

The models are fast but actual writing of the crops to disk is slow.  Sure, using an SSD would speed it up but I'm sure ffmpeg would greatly speed it up.
Some of the challenges with the crops:

the output size is always 128x128
the input size is variable
the crop moves on every frame

My process for extracting crops is simple using cv2.imwrite(output_crop_path, crop) in a for loop.
I've done experiments trying to use sndcommand and filter_complex.  I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67508233/4447761 but it outputs an image with black below the crop and the image gets wrapped around on the x axis.


Are you trying to create a cropped dataset for training? If you don't need to view the images, why not do what Christoph Rackwitz says and accumulate all the images as a big tensor and save as a hdf5 file or something similar for general binary data?

I'm unsure about the goal of the question. are you asking how to write a video file?

@kesh yes, I'm creating a cropped dataset for training.  I'm also extracting the crops as an intermediate step during production.  Saving them all as a big hdf5 tensor is a great suggestion, though it is nice to see the intermediate results for debugging purposes but isn't a requirement.

Don't store the pictures.
Store just the sequence of bounding boxes.
Then, for whatever you wanted to do with that mountain of individual images, instead decode the video and read the sequence of boxes, and take your crops out of it like that, on the fly.
I'd recommend using PyAV for video reading. It gives you the presentation timestamps reliably. You shouldn't even need them, but having them along in the file can be very helpful for debugging.
Maybe you want to use pandas to write and read such a file. CSV is a popular format.
Another advantage of keeping the boxes like that: you can work on this sequence, maybe smooth it, or mix in the results of an optical tracker (sticks like glue but also creeps over time).

If you really do need to write a video, then write a video. Individual frames as files are a serious burden on most file systems, let alone file managers. Again I would recommend PyAV to write a video. It gives you all kinds of control over how to do it, and the basic code isn't all that much. PyAV comes with examples.

Thanks for the feedback!  This is a great point, and I think you're right for the production pipeline.
'I'm still interested in writing out the crop images quickly for the deep learning pipeline, where the action recognition model will take in 7 sequential cropped images and will perform action detection on them.
Let me know though if you think even that should be done with a video.

If you do want to save the frames as images, then my suggestion is to Popen an FFmpeg subprocess to take a sequence of cropped frames and write to image2 muxer. Then, you do the read and crop operation as Christoph Rackwitz described and write each cropped frame to the stdin of the FFmpeg writer process. Once all frames are processed you can soft-kill the writer by signaling it SIGINT or CTRL_C_EVENT:
sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT if os_name == "nt" else signal.SIGINT
proc.send_signal(sig)

Above assumes you're using a recent FFmpeg version. If not, you may need to send q to stdin. Also, if you figured out PyAV then maybe you can set up the writer all in Python and don't worry about Popen process management.
This prevent you to start up the image encoder for every frame. But no idea how much faster...
If you're open to using another package, I can outline how to do the above with my ffmpegio package.
Another (obvious but perhaps tedious) solution if your computational/memory/storage capacities are not maxed out is to spawn multiple Python processes (multiprocessing) and run multiple instances of the cropping operation in parallel.

ffmpeg subprocess is more costly and more fragile than simply calling into the ffmpeg library. that's why I also recommended PyAV for this. you should absolutely check it out. there are many examples and the API is reasonably simple. don't use any "wrapper" that just runs ffmpeg as a subprocess. -- oh since ffmpegio is your package, I think I see why you'd recommend it :)

@ChristophRackwitz - Oh I'm fully aware of what it is, and it's actually what I dreamed to build in Matlab a decade before I made a switch to Python. I'd push PyAV for a production project, but a wrapper (or "the" wrapper? :)) suffices for my research use and convenience.

That being said. I should study PyAV to see how it's handling the recent drastic changes in the FFmpeg implementation, becoming more threaded with the use of a scheduler at the top (tool) level.
