FFmpeg dynamic cropping using sendcmd correct syntax?
I'm trying to dynamically crop a video using FFmpeg's sendcmd filter based on coordinates specified in a text file, but the crop commands do not seem to be taking effect. Here's the format of the commands I've tried and the corresponding FFmpeg command I'm using.
Following the documentation https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd, commands in the text file (coordinates.txt) like this:
0.05 [enter] crop w=607:h=1080:x=0:y=0;
0.11 [enter] crop w=607:h=1080:x=0:y=0;
...

Ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i '10s.mp4' -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=coordinates.txt" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -r 30 output.mp4

This doesn’t seem to do anything.
And with the commands in the text file (coordinates.txt) like this:
0.05    crop w 607, crop h 1080, crop x 0, crop y 0;
0.11    crop w 607, crop h 1080, crop x 0, crop y 0;
...

Ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i '10s.mp4' -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=coordinates.txt,crop" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -r 30 output.mp4

(following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67508233/1967110)
This one does something, but something very messy. It looks like it crops at the correct x, but does not take into account the y, w or h, and it puts the crop at the right side of the input video.
Edit: what I’m trying to do is create a 607x1080 (portrait format, 9:16) video from a 1920x1080 video, with the x parameter varying across time (imagine sliding horizontally a 9:16 frame over a 16:9 video). So fixed w, h and y, just x varying.
I’m using this ffmpeg version:
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
configuration: --prefix=/home/ffmpeg-builder/release --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs=-lm --disable-doc --disable-debug --disable-shared --disable-ffprobe --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avfilter --enable-filters --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-cuvid --toolchain=hardened --disable-stripping --enable-opengl --pkgconfigdir=/home/ffmpeg-builder/release/lib/pkgconfig --extra-cflags='-I/home/ffmpeg-builder/release/include -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/ffmpeg-builder/release/lib -fstack-protector -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ' --extra-cxxflags=' -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc ' --extra-libs='-ldl -lrt -lpthread' --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-gmp --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libshine --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --ld=g++ --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-nonfree --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-pthreads --extra-libs=-lgomp


in my case it works properly if commands starts from 0 (not 0.05), and it has same w and h values in all lines

@БаярГончикжапов the first or second format I mention?

for example: 0 crop w 640, crop h 640, crop x 0, crop y 0; 2 crop x 100; 4 crop x 200; 6 crop x 300; 8 crop x 400;. it is not nesessary write w and h at every line

@БаярГончикжапов and you’re runing this file with ffmpeg -i 'input.mp4' -filter_complex "[0:v]sendcmd=f=coordinates.txt,crop" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -r 29.97 output.mp4 (with ,crop at the end) ? If yes can you post a full example, I can’t get this command to work, it’s either not working (without ,crop) or cropping with a messy result (with ,crop)

Your first command does nothing because there is no instance of the the "crop" filter where the commands can be sent to. You need to append “,crop” to the filter list in order to create an instance of the crop filter.

Ok so the only command I got working so far, taken from https://video.stackexchange.com/posts/19403/revisions , is this:
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex_script file.txt -map "[out]" output.mp4

with file.txt like this
nullsrc=WxH:r=FPS[cv];
[cv][0]overlay=-X0:-Y0:shortest=1:enable='eq(n\,0)'[b0];
[b0][0]overlay=-X1:-Y1:shortest=1:enable='eq(n\,1)'[b1];
[b1][0]overlay=-X2:-Y2:shortest=1:enable='eq(n\,2)'[b2];
...
[bm-1][0]overlay=-Xm:-Ym:shortest=1:enable='eq(n\,m)'[out]

this takes about 40s to crop a 1920x1080 5s 30fps video to a 606x1080 video (on google colab, so low-level cpu, and without gpu). BUT it also causes Out of memory errors as soon as more than 900 frames need to be cropped, on a 12GB RAM machine (see https://superuser.com/questions/1839180/ffmpeg-out-of-memory-issues-with-filter-complex-script).
I also tried to first decompose the video into each of its frames, crop each frame, and reassemble the video. Here is the code:
def decompose_video(video_path, frames_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(frames_dir):
        os.makedirs(frames_dir)
    command = [
        'ffmpeg', '-i', video_path, 
        os.path.join(frames_dir, 'frame_%04d.png')
    ]
    subprocess.run(command, check=True)

def read_crop_values(crop_file):
    with open(crop_file, 'r') as file:
        crops = [line.strip().split(',') for line in file]
    return crops

def apply_crop(frames_dir, crops):
    cropped_frames_dir = frames_dir + '_cropped'
    if not os.path.exists(cropped_frames_dir):
        os.makedirs(cropped_frames_dir)
    
    for i, crop in enumerate(crops, 1):
        x, y, w, h = crop
        input_frame = os.path.join(frames_dir, f'frame_{i:04d}.png')
        output_frame = os.path.join(cropped_frames_dir, f'frame_{i:04d}.png')
        command = [
            'ffmpeg', '-i', input_frame,
            '-filter:v', f'crop={w}:{h}:{x}:{y}',
            output_frame
        ]
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)

def recreate_video(cropped_frames_dir, output_video_path):
    command = [
        'ffmpeg', '-y', '-loglevel', 'verbose', '-r', '29.97', '-f', 'image2', '-i', 
        os.path.join(cropped_frames_dir, 'frame_%04d.png'),
        '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-crf', '23', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
        output_video_path
    ]
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("FFmpeg failed with error:")
        print(e.stderr.decode()) 

video_path = 'input.mp4'
frames_dir = 'frames'
crop_file = 'crop_values.txt'
output_video_path = 'output.mp4'

decompose_video(video_path, frames_dir)
crops = read_crop_values(crop_file)
apply_crop(frames_dir, crops)
recreate_video(frames_dir + '_cropped', output_video_path)

and in crop_values.txt you just put x, y, w, h:
0,0,606,1080
8,0,606,1080
17,0,606,1080

It also works but is quite a bit slower (1m40 for the same video).

tested variant:
#!/bin/bash
echo "#test crop
0 crop w 607, crop h 1080, crop x 0, crop y 0;
1 crop x 200;
2 crop x 400;
3 crop x 600;
" > coordinates.txt
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 4 -r 30000/1001 -i "1920x1080.jpg" -filter_complex "sendcmd=f=coordinates.txt,crop" /tmp/out.mp4 -y
ffplay /tmp/out.mp4


do not add -pix_fmt ... this option resets output resolution to input.

